# How to retrieve the check state of CheckBox from database while the CheckBox control is on the DataRepeater

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, datarepeater

I want to retrieve the checked state of the unbound `CheckBox` control on the `DataRepeater` and database using C# in win forms. I dragged the "Task State" field from Task table as a label containing the 0 (which will be used as `false`) and 1 (which will be used as `true` for `checkBox1.Checked`).

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0hwo.jpg)

as you can see in the image, I want the unbound CheckBox to take it's check state from translating those 1s and 0s from the label under the CheckBox (green arrowed).

This is the code I'm using to set the checkboxes:

```
private void dataRepeater3_DrawItem(object sender, Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.DataRepeaterItemEventArgs e) 
{
    if (((Label)dataRepeater3.CurrentItem.Controls["stateLabel1"]).Text == "1") 
    { 
        ((CheckBox)dataRepeater3.CurrentItem.Controls["checkBox1"]).Checked = true; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        ((CheckBox)dataRepeater3.CurrentItem.Controls["checkBox1"]).Checked = false; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: so, you want the checkbox checked if the label is a 1, and unchecked if the label is a 0?

Comment: absolutely right, in fact I wrote this code, but still it does not work properly: 
`private void dataRepeater3_DrawItem(object sender, Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.DataRepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (((Label)dataRepeater3.CurrentItem.Controls["stateLabel1"]).Text == "1")
            {
                ((CheckBox)dataRepeater3.CurrentItem.Controls["checkBox1"]).Checked = true;
            }
            else
            {
                ((CheckBox)dataRepeater3.CurrentItem.Controls["checkBox1"]).Checked = false;
            }
        }`

Comment: when does DrawItem get called? have you set a breakpoint to step through it?

Comment: I directly wrote this code to the DrawItem event of the DataRepeater, so when I checked it, it works for drawing every single row of the DataRepeater. it works for the first row of the bunch of tasks related to a project. but when you select another project, it checks the tasks which their related label is 0. and every time you change the projects, the code works randomly. sometimes when you click on the wrong checked item, it will correct itself, but only for one time.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not very familiar with VB... You could try in a different event, like VisibleChanged. Also I would make sure that the controls are named the way you think they are (can you have multiple "checkBox1" items?)

Comment: this C#, not VB. and now I found a way that works fine, but you have to click on every row of the DataRepeater(so the CurrentItem will be updated and then works fine). is there any other property  (e.g NextItem instead of CurrentItem) so I won't need to click on every row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through the controls each time you draw the repeater. Try this in your DrawItem method:

```
foreach ( DataRepeaterItem rowItem in dataRepeater1.Controls )
    {
        if (((Label)rowItem.Controls["stateLabel1"]).Text == "1") 
        { 
            ((CheckBox)rowItem.Controls["checkBox1"]).Checked = true; 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            ((CheckBox)rowItem.Controls["checkBox1"]).Checked = false; 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Man, that one worked perfectly. thanks a lot.